# Detect User Changes In HTML Code at Client Side

Tags: php, html

when a user input form is displayed to a client (developed in PHP), if a client open its source using firebug or something like that and modify some restrictions on the form (e.g. increase maximum length / change field name etc.) .and submits the form to the server. how can i detect on the server that the form was modified at runtime on client or any type of change.
example:

> Text Field `<input type="hidden" name="update_12" readonly />`
>   changed to
>      `<input type="text" name="update_12" />`

every page might have different number fields and different types of fields. is there any possible way like page checksum , field checksum etc.

Comment: Why do you need that? Detection of bad users? You actually have to deal with users data as potentially dangerous. You can't rely on it, so move all sensitive logic to the server.

Comment: there are some restrictions on the client side that he may not edit some data and as well as he is forced to provide some field data. if he want to cheat and edit it using the firebug like something, the restrictions are removed (restrictions applied using jQuery). how can i detect those changes on server side when form is submitted.

Comment: Why don't you move checking logic to server? If editing `field-5` is prohibited, just don't save it even if it is passed in `$_POST`.

Comment: it is required on the client as well. i know i can apply all checks to server side. but it makes development more time taking as to apply checks on both sides. :) . any quick solution ?

Comment: What do you think will you achieve with client-side checks? You need to perform validation on the server side anyway. A "bad user" can simply post whatever he wants with curl. If you worry about development time just don't make any client-side checks because they are useless against "experienced bad users".

Comment: Your server is a box receiving HTTP requests. Only the content of those requests count. Whatever is happening client-side is completely irrelevant. There are many more ways to send arbitrary HTTP requests to your server than using your HTML code. Trying to protect the HTML from being spoofed is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need to validate your data on the Server side. Even without using firebug or some other browser debugging tools, a user can simply send an invalid request using CURL or even Postman. Client side only validation is a really bad idea